# How to prevent Rails from displaying personal information when Couldn't find Article with 'id'=

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I went through most of this guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html a long time ago.

I set up an articles controller and when I create a new article, a new number is generated such as

```
https://www.zzz.com/articles/1
https://www.zzz.com/articles/2
https://www.zzz.com/articles/3
```

I just noticed that if I type a number that doesn't exist, I get an error that says

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ArticlesController#show
```

Then it displays information that I dont want people to see such as

```
Rails.root: /home/myname/myapp
```

How do I just display a 404 error?

I've tried adding stuff like this to the application controller but it doesn't help:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_404
  # Render 404 page when record not found
    def render_404      
       render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html", :status => 404
    end
end
```

I'm currently running in development mode instead of production.  Does that matter?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it matters that you are running in `development` mode instead of `production`. Because in `development` the application hat other defaults and try are optimized to help developers for example by showing error messages.

The defaults in the `production` are different and optimized for applications running on a production server: The application will run faster and will not send error messages to the browser.

If you want to test that behavior you might what to set `consider_all_requests_local` in your `config/environments/development.rb` to `false` (See [Rails docs about configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)). That disables sending debug information to the browser.

However, I suggest running applications on servers in the `production` environment.

Answer (score 0):

As spickermann has already pointed out, it does matter.

The reason for this is the setting of the `consider_all_requests_local` configuration which determines how much information error messages display. In `development` mode, this setting is set to `true` while it is `false` in `production`.

If you want to see beforehand what it will look like in `production` alter the corresponding setting

```
# Show full error reports and disable caching.
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

in `config/environments/development.rb`